# Bottom overflowed by 164 pixels and after a hot reload for attempting to fix, Unimplemented handling of missing static target appears

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

my app no longer works, this works yesterday but no matter what I try to debug this even when I didnt change anything and just hot reloads, the Unimplemented error appears.

It works well yesterday. The error on my projects are posted below. it says with a Column widget but I dont know where since it works well yesterday.

> IT should start with the LoginScreen and not directly to homescreen, for some reason when I tried my github clone of the app that Im making,it go straight to homescreen and not login screen first.
>
> Also, I didnt do any changes to my homescreen but on the login.dart, register.dart only since yesterday, the firebase authentication works and the app proceeds to the homescreen
>
> Ive added the images of the errors

you can try to clone my project https://github.com/rolandopeda/syncshop

**ERROR**

```
I/flutter ( 7581): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 7581): The following assertion was thrown during layout:
I/flutter ( 7581): A RenderFlex overflowed by 2.0 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 7581):
I/flutter ( 7581): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 7581):   Column 
lib\login\login.dart:129
I/flutter ( 7581):
I/flutter ( 7581): The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
I/flutter ( 7581): The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
I/flutter ( 7581): black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
I/flutter ( 7581): Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
I/flutter ( 7581): RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
I/flutter ( 7581): This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
I/flutter ( 7581): seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
I/flutter ( 7581): ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
I/flutter ( 7581): like a ListView.
I/flutter ( 7581): The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#7e604 relayoutBoundary=up9 OVERFLOWING:
I/flutter ( 7581):   creator: Column ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
I/flutter ( 7581):     RawGestureDetector ← GestureDetector ← MouseRegion ← Semantics ← _FocusMarker ← Focus ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 7581):   parentData: <none> (can use size)
I/flutter ( 7581):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=331.4, h=12.0)
I/flutter ( 7581):   size: Size(96.0, 12.0)
I/flutter ( 7581):   direction: vertical
I/flutter ( 7581):   mainAxisAlignment: start
I/flutter ( 7581):   mainAxisSize: max
I/flutter ( 7581):   crossAxisAlignment: center
I/flutter ( 7581):   verticalDirection: down
I/flutter ( 7581): ◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
I/flutter ( 7581): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 7581): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 164 pixels on the bottom.

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _CompileTimeError was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
Unimplemented handling of missing static target

The relevant error-causing widget was
    MyApp
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vmembershipofficial/login/register.dart';
import 'package:vmembershipofficial/screens/home_screen.dart';

import 'login/login.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget _getScreenId() {
    return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged, //check if we are login
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return HomeScreen();
      } else {
        return LoginPage();
      }
    },
    );
  }
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: _getScreenId(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routes:  {
        HomeScreen.id: (context) => HomeScreen(),
        RegisterPage.id: (context) => RegisterPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**login**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vmembershipofficial/login/register.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff0D192A),
        body: Container(
          child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Container(
                width: 120,
                height: 120,
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 0),
                child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/vlogo.png"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Login",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            //TEXTFIELDS //
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                        child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: "Enter Your Email",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400]),
                        )),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                  Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                        child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: "Enter Your Password",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400]),
                        )),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 50),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 50,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(211, 184, 117, 100)),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "Login",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 40),
                  Container(
                    height: 10,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "Don't have an account?",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12.0),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 12.0),
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(
                              () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => RegisterPage()),
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            "Register Here",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(211, 184, 117, 100),
                                fontSize: 12.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    child: Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "Forgot password?",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**homescreen**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:vmembershipofficial/Widgets/afterintroducing.dart';
import 'package:vmembershipofficial/Widgets/discount_carousel.dart';
import 'package:vmembershipofficial/Widgets/header_carousel.dart';
import 'package:vmembershipofficial/Widgets/introducing_vmembership.dart';


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static final  String id = 'home_screen';

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
    int _currentTab = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
            padding:  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
              child: Text("Explore V!", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
              ),
          SizedBox(height:5.0),
         HeaderCarousel(),
         SizedBox(height: 30.0),
         Padding(
           padding:  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
           child: Text("Discount", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 20.0),
           ),
         ),
         Padding(
           padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 5.0),
           child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),),
         ),
         DiscountCarousel(),
         SizedBox(height: 30.0),
         Padding(
           padding:  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
           child: Text(
             "Introducing V Membership Plus", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
           ),
         ),
          Padding(
           padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 4.0),
           child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),),
         ),
         VmembershipPlus(),
         SizedBox(height: 30.0),
         Padding(
           padding:  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
           child: Text(
             "Lorem Ipsum", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
           ),
         ),
          Padding(
           padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 4.0),
           child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),),
         ),
         SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
         AfterIntroducing(),
         SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
         Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
           child: FlatButton(
               padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              color: Colors.blue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
              },
              child: Text(
              "LOREM IPSUM",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            ),
           ),
         ),
                SizedBox(height: 50.0,),
        ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: _currentTab, //makes a new variable called current Tab
          onTap: (int value) {
            setState(
              () {
                _currentTab = value;
              },
            );
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search, size: 30.0),
              title: Text('Search', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
              title: Text('Favorites', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              title: Text('Home', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.message),
              title: Text('Messages', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              // icon: CircleAvatar(
              //   backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
              //       'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/31.jpg'),
              //   radius: 15.0,
              // ),
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
              title: Text('Account', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**register**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vmembershipofficial/services/auth_service.dart';

class RegisterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static final String id = 'register';

  @override
  _RegisterPageState createState() => _RegisterPageState();
}

class _RegisterPageState extends State<RegisterPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _name, _email, _password;

  _submit() {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      AuthService.signUpUser(context, _name, _email, _password); //
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff0D192A),
        body: Container(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Container(
                      width: 120,
                      height: 120,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 0),
                      child: Image(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/images/vlogo.png"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text("Register an Account",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 20)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text("Email Address",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 10.0,
                                          color: Color(0xFFD3B875),),),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xFFD3B875),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    labelText: "Email Address",
                                    labelStyle:
                                        TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                  validator: (input) => !input.contains("@")
                                      ? 'Please enter a valid email'
                                      : null,
                                  onSaved: (input) => _email = input,
                                ),
                              ),
                            )),
                        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text("Choose Password",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 10.0,
                                          color: Color(0xFFD3B875),),),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xFFD3B875),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    labelText: "Password",
                                    labelStyle:
                                        TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                  validator: (input) => input.length < 8
                                      ? 'Must be at least 8 characters'
                                      : null,
                                  onSaved: (input) => _password = input,
                                  obscureText: true,
                                ),
                              ),
                            )),
                        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text("Choose a Name",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 10.0,
                                          color: Color(0xFFD3B875),),),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xFFD3B875),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    labelText: "Name",
                                    labelStyle:
                                        TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                  validator: (input) => input.trim().isEmpty
                                      ? 'Enter a valid name'
                                      : null,
                                  onSaved: (input) => _name = input,
                                ),
                              ),
                            )),
                        SizedBox(height: 50),
                        Container(
                          width: 250.0,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: _submit,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: Text(
                              'Sign Up',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 40),
                        Container(
                          height: 20,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                "Already have an account?",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12.0),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 12.0),
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    Navigator.pop(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) =>
                                                RegisterPage()));
                                  });
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  "Login Here",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color.fromRGBO(211, 184, 117, 100),
                                      fontSize: 12.0),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**LOGIN SCREEN**
[image: loginscreen]

**HOT RELOAD ERROR - this occurs whether I changed something or not**
[image: hotreload error]

Comment: Post the relevant code on Stack Overflow, don't just give as a Github project with all of the code in the project. B.T.W. I get a 404 Page Not Found when trying to navigate to Github project.

Comment: @Jack ok Ill try posting it, maybe Ill post my main.dart and login screen and home screen. Im kinda lost tbh where the error is relevant as theres too many columns. But I think its from the Login Screen.

Comment: Is there a column widget on line 129 in lib\login\login.dart?

Comment: hi @Jack I updated my code and put more details. Nope, its a curly bracket from a Container

Comment: the error pops up in the login screen, right?

Comment: is there any way you could post a screenshot of the app when the error occurs on your emulator/device

Comment: okay wait Ill take a lunch for the mean time and get back here

Comment: @Jack Ive added the images

Comment: i think its on the emulator part for some reason. I tried it on a mobile device and its okay BUT after trying to register this error occurs: PlatformException(FirebaseException, An internal error has occurred. [ 7: ], null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running your login screen code on dart pad and this is what i'm getting

your container thats holding your Email TextField is taking up 50% of the screen width and height.

[image]

I would suggest you remove the

```
 width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
```

from your container .

Comment: Hi this fixed it. And for some reason, i think the emulator is acting up. I tried on a mobile phone and it works BUT when I try to register a new account this error appears https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59386888/app-works-perfectly-yesterday-and-now-an-error-platformexceptionfirebaseexcepti

sorry if Im asking too much, I tried searching to no avail.

Comment: no problem ..check out this github issue regarding firebase login  https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/290

Comment: thanks! I also fixed the second issue, it was a firewall issue that my lil bro messed up earlier