# App works perfectly yesterday and now an error PlatformException(FirebaseException, An internal error has occurred. [ 7: ], null) appears

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Hi I have a flutter app that is perfectly working yesterday. I even manage to signup and it registered in my Firebase console but for some reason when i try it today (didnt change anything code whatsoever)

This error appears when trying to register for a new account

```
PlatformException(FirebaseException, An internal error has occurred. [ 7: ], null)
```

[image: The image I provided shows the account I tried to register yesterday]

Comment: check this issue https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/290

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an actual error. Happened with me too yesterday, Fixed this with.

1. Check your internet connectivity (or firewall)
2. Restart your emulator and try again.

Comment: Ugh! this fixed it lmao im too noob lol. But I think checking my firewall also works, I just remembered my bro uses the computer earlier.

Comment: Glad that helped:)